# Current is the same for thin segments of a conductor?

Tags: electric-current

Given a finite conductive medium of length($L$) where $10$$A$ DC is flowing, and I considered slicing(for analysis) multiple layers(a,b,c) of extremely short lengths. Is the magnitude of current still the same? $10A$ for all segments that are $\frac{L}{n}$? $n$ being factors of $10$ to $100$ and beyond?

[image]

I'm trying correlate current flow to length to understand other possible factors, aside from it's increase resistance.

Comment: Yes, of course it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The current should still be the same, if you are talking about a thought experiment.  This is because $R=\frac{\rho L}{A}$ and the total resistance will still be the same whether you have $n$ segments of total length $L$ or 1 segment of length $L$.  Therefore, for a fixed applied DC voltage you should get a the same DC current.

However, if you do the real experiment, you will find that the resistance is more likely to increase and therefore the current will decrease.  This is because of the small air gaps between the different segments.  The more segments you have, the more air gaps you will get and I expect the current to decrease with the number of segments (I expect it to be linear because the total length of air gaps will increase linearly with the number of cuts if all the gaps have the same width).

You will also inevitably lose a tiny bit of material every time you cut through the material.  This will lead to a slight decrease in resistance (and therefore a slight increase in current).  But this effect should be tiny compared to the air gap effect as the amount of material that you will lose will be negligible as long as you make good cuts.

Answer (score 0):

The current is the same because the charge is conserved. If there is no charge accumulation in any segment, the amount of charges that enter into that segment in any given amount of time is equal to the amount of charge that exits the segment. And that is the definition of the current.